# lxc config file overwritted when rebooting CT

Tags: proxmox, apparmor

i'm trying to install Sandstorm on a debian 8 lxc container under proxmox 4.4.

According to my search (and [this post](https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/i-would-like-to-see-an-appliance-for-sandstorm-io.24773/) ) i need to to edit the apparmor container's config file in `/var/lib/lxc/*lxcId*/conf` and reboot the CT

but anny line i add to this file get suppressed as son as i reboot the CT ....
(i precise that i edit this file with root privileges and saving is ok until i reboot the CT)
What am i missing ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok i was wrong. The apparmor's LXC config files are in `/etc/pve/lxc/` then one conf file for each container created.